# Finding closest value if date is equal to a certain date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I want a formula that finds the moneyness closest to 100 for a certain date.
I made this formula:

```
=(IF("02-01-2009"=C2:C131104;INDEX($K$2:$K$131104;MATCH(MIN(ABS(K2:K131104-100));ABS(K2:K131104-100);0));""))
```

But it searches the entire sheet instead of only the rows where the date is 02-01-2009.

---

Data

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours won't work because you need to perform the `IF` condition before you search for your value. If you are looking to do this without any additional columns (as your attempt does), a more correct formula would be:

```
=INDEX($K$2:$K$25;MATCH(MIN(IF($C$2:$C$25=$T$9;ABS($K$2:$K$25-100);1000));IF($C$2:$C$25=$T$9;ABS($K$2:$K$25-100);1001);0))
```

Make sure to enter this with **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER** since it's an array formula.

Here cell T9 holds the date I'm matching against. 1000 is somewhat arbitrary (larger than your difference from 100 will ever be). I check the date. If it matches I return moneyness - 100 and if it doesn't I return our arbitrary 1000 so these are excluded from the minimum. Once the minimum finds the smallest difference that matches our date, I perform the match and subsequent index to grab the first moneyness value with the minimum difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76803/discussion-between-anwi12ad-and-barry-houdini).